# Can't initialize the button in dialog in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having a Floating Action Button listener with `AlertDiaolog` inside. And I want to use my buttons from XML. And if I want to write an `onClickListener()` for them.

So in Java I have to initialize it like:

```
butAdd = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_add)
butAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Some code
    }
```

But when I trying to use:

```
var butAdd = dialog?.findViewById(R.id.btn_add) as Button;
```

in Kotlin it's incorrect

So any suggestions how to fix it? What'is wrong with listeners?

Here is my code of Floating Action Button:

```
fab?.setOnClickListener {
    diaolg = AlertDialog.Builder(this@Cards)
    val linearlayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_password, null)
    diaolg?.setView(linearlayout)
    ?.setTitle("Add a new password")
    ?.setCancelable(true)

    var login = findViewById(R.id.login) as EditText
    var password = findViewById(R.id.password) as EditText
    var title = findViewById(R.id.title) as EditText

    var butAdd = diaolg?.findViewById(R.id.btn_add) as Button
    var butCancel = diaolg?.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel) as Button

    butAdd.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        fun onClick(v:View){
        }
    })
    butCancel.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        fun onClick(v:View){
        }
    })
    diaolg?.create()
    diaolg?.show()
}
```

Comment: 'it's incorrect' - not really a precise description.

Comment: It says "Unresolved reference: findByView" and makes it red

Answer (score 3):

please find id by using

```
             var butAdd = linearlayout.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_add) as Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever class you're in has no `findViewById` method.
You have to `findViewById` on the inflated layout, so:

```
 var login = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.login) as EditText
```

Also, I dont think you need to have the `?` on the dialog, it cannot be null. 
Also, I would make your views `val`s instead of `var`s.

Comment: I have just made as you said but now it throws a TypeCastException on `var login = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.login) as EditText`

Comment: @ПавелБределев You should provide a. a full stracktrace and b. the XML layout you inflate for the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

import this line in your Activity

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="submit" />
```

**import this line in your Activity**

// Using R.layout.activity_main from the main source set

//activity_main is your layout file name

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

```
 btn_submit.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Its work for me.